# App appearance changed after migration from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

We have recently migrated our app from Eclipse to Android Studio, as Eclipse was having more and more issues as it stopped being adequately supported.

We are using the AppCompat libraries and themes (min SDK 9; target SDK 21). However, the app background is now dark grey instead of black, and the appearance of the CheckBox has changed (boxes are a bit smaller, checks are solid blue background with grey checks instead of clear background with white checks).

I have not changed my styles.xml. Is there a difference between the Theme.AppCompat included in Android Studio and the one included in the support library in Eclipse?

I have noticed that we no longer need a separate library project for the AppCompat support library.

I have searched but I haven't found anyone with similar issues. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I don't mind adjusting our styles if needed, but before I do that I wanted to make sure it's not an obscure error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of AppCompat, [AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), moved to following the Lollipop conventions, the [Material Design color palette](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette), and includes widget tinting bringing much of the Material theme to older devices.

While you can and most definitely should move to this structure, you can see if reverting to a previous version of AppCompat brings you back to your existing style:

In your `build.gradle` file, look for a line such as

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
```

(It may be a specific version rather than a `+`).

Change it to version 19 (the previous version) by replacing it with:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+"
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thank you.